# How to display a Future<File> image?

Tags: flutter

My app load image from samba (instead of url) and then save thumbnail in local, so I can not use `Image.network();`, previouly I loaded image Uint8List from samba and then use `Image.memory(bytes);` to display image, it work, but I also have to combine it with Local Cache, so I save image file with flutter_cache_manager package `DefaultCacheManager()`(using `(await DefaultCacheManager().getFileFromCache()).file`), but the problem is, the `DefaultCacheManager()` only can return  `Future<File>` cache instead of `File`, so I cannot use `Image.file(cacheFile)` to display image.

I have to try the `FutureBuilder` to solve the problem, but it cause flash in the image displaying.

I have considered to use `FadeInImage` and make my own `ImageProvider` to feed my need, but it is difficult for me to write ImageProvider.

In conclusion, I want to make something like:

```
Image.futureFile(Future<File>)
```

to use the Future cache return by `DefaultCacheManager()` to display a local image.If it cannot be solve(for example, a local cache file api should not return Future), I will conside to use another cache library.

Comment: why don't you use the FutureBuilder and just display a Loading screen while the data is not yet ready?

Comment: @Cedric As far as I can found, FutureBuilder will cause flash in image displaying when I switching the app page , even when  I save the FutureBuilder in initState() and cache them, and after that, now I think loading image from local cache should not use future, use future 
will cause many problem(most relate to the image flash), it may be not a corret way.

Comment: what is `DefaultCacheManager()`? - there is no such thing in public flutter API - at least for v1.26

Comment: The local cache probably fetches from disk which is done async in Flutter, so in my opinion, it should return a Future;

Comment: DefaultCacheManager() is from `flutter_cache_manager` package, sorry I forget it .

Comment: @EdmoreMGoneseDigolodollarz I have check flutter api, it like `Image(image: FileImage(File(path)))`  , so in future api, load local file is not need future.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I end up with a custom `ImageProvider`, it refers to `FileImage`, I don't master at this so it may have problem (for example I don't test it with gif). After all, now image flashing is better than the FutureBuilder solution.

```
class CacheImageProvider extends ImageProvider<CacheImageProvider> {
  final String fileId;//the cache id use to get cache

  CacheImageProvider(this.fileId);

  @override
  ImageStreamCompleter load(CacheImageProvider key, DecoderCallback decode) {
    return MultiFrameImageStreamCompleter(
      codec: _loadAsync(decode),
      scale: 1.0,
      debugLabel: fileId,
      informationCollector: () sync* {
        yield ErrorDescription('Path: $fileId');
      },
    );
  }

  Future<Codec> _loadAsync(DecoderCallback decode) async {
    // the DefaultCacheManager() encapsulation, it get cache from local storage.
    final Uint8List bytes = await (await CacheThumbnail.getThumbnail(fileId)).readAsBytes();

    if (bytes.lengthInBytes == 0) {
      // The file may become available later.
      PaintingBinding.instance?.imageCache?.evict(this);
      throw StateError('$fileId is empty and cannot be loaded as an image.');
    }

    return await decode(bytes);
  }

  @override
  Future<CacheImageProvider> obtainKey(ImageConfiguration configuration) {
    return SynchronousFuture<CacheImageProvider>(this);
  }
  
  //the custom == and hashCode is need, because the ImageProvider use to get the memory cache.
  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    if (other.runtimeType != runtimeType) return false;
    bool res = other is CacheImageProvider && other.fileId == fileId;
    return res;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => fileId.hashCode;

  @override
  String toString() => '${objectRuntimeType(this, 'CacheImageProvider')}("$fileId")';
}
```

and use it:

```
Image(image: CacheImageProvider(_data[index].fileId))
```

Comment: how to get CacheThumbnail?

Answer (score -1):

```
// This should be in a callback or outside the build() function:
File _file = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(file);

// In the widget tree:
Image.file(_file);
```

Comment: Add more details or information of the use of your code.